# Python payroll calculator

Tags: python, calculator

I am stumped with how to write this in python code. Can anyone help?

***For hours over 60, you need to calculate the overage above 60 to multiply at the 2x pay rate + the hours between 40 and 60  to be compensated at 1.5x rate + the first 40 hours at the regular rate.****

Answer (score 1):

You should at least provide your initial effort to solve your problem with your question, but how about this:

```
def calculate_total(hours, rate):
    if hours > 60:
        over_60 = hours - 60
    else:
        over_60 = 0
    if hours > 40:
        over_40 = hours - 40 - over_60
    else:
        over_40 = 0
    under_40 = hours - over_60 - over_40

    return under_40 * rate + over_40 * rate * 1.5 + over_60 * rate * 2
```

You may the call this function using:

```
calculate_total(75, 12)
```